# How can I get a list of databases and collections on a MongoDB server?

Tags: c, mongodb

I'm writing a GUI client for MongoDB in C. I use the [C driver for MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/C+Language+Center). I want to get a list of databases and their collections, but I can't find any functions in the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.4/api/mongo_8h.html) to do that.

How can I get a list of databases and collections using the C driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `mongo_run_command(mongo *conn, const char * db, bson *command, bson *out)` where your `command` is a BSON command. You should be able to use the commands defined [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/List+of+Database+Commands). Note that some of the commands require that they are issued on the database `admin`. So in the mongodb shell one could query the list of databases like this:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand({listDatabases: 1})
{
    "databases" : [
        {
            "name" : "geo",
            "sizeOnDisk" : 14975762432,
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "local",
            "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
            "empty" : true
        }
    ],
    "totalSize" : 14975762432,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

With the result of this operation, you can query each database for the available collections. I haven't tried the above using the C interface, but I believe that you should be able to achieve the same thing by calling `mongo_run_command` and passing the appropriate parameters.

Comment: For the list of collections in a database, switch to the database with "use dbname", and then run db.getCollectionNames().

Answer (score 4):

The other answers here seem half complete, or not even relevant to the C/C++ interface.  After much looking, here's what worked for me:

```
string serverHost("127.0.0.1:27017");
mongo::DBClientConnection conn;
string errmsg;
if( conn.connect( serverHost, errmsg ) )
{
  BSONObj cmd = mongo::fromjson( "{listDatabases: 1}" );
  BSONObj info;
  if( conn.runCommand( "admin", cmd, info ) )
  {
    BSONElement arrayel = info.getField("databases");
    std::vector<BSONElement> mdArray = arrayel.Array();
    std::vector<BSONElement>::iterator iter;
    for( iter=mdArray.begin(); iter!=mdArray.end(); ++iter )
    {
      BSONElement element = *iter;
      BSONObj obj = element.Obj();

      // HERE IS THE DATABASE NAME
      string dbname = obj.getStringField("name");

      // HERE IS THE LIST OF COLLECTIONS, BUT MAY NEED TO IGNORE ONE
      // TITLED "system.indexes"
      list<string> collNamespaces =
          conn.getCollectionNames(dbname);

      list<string>::iterator iter2 = collNamespaces.begin();
      while( iter2 != collNamespaces.end() )
      {
        // EACH ENTRY HAS THE FULL NAMESPACE ("database:collection").
        // Use this method to strip off the database name
        string collectionName = mongo::nsGetCollection(*iter2);

        ++iter2;
      } // END WHILE iterate through collections
    } // END WHILE iterate through databases
  } // END IF runCommand() returned success
} // END IF database connected
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the collections name in a database you can use `mongoc_database_get_collection_names`

```
bson_error_t error;
char **strv;
unsigned i;

if((strv = mongoc_database_get_collection_names (database, &error))) 
{
    for(i = 0; strv [i]; i++)
        printf ("%s\n", strv [i]);
    bson_strfreev (strv);
} 
else
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Command failed: %s\n", error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Matlab](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/mongo-matlab-driver/blob/master/api_mongo.c) driver provides two functions: **mongo_get_databases**() and:  **mongo_get_database_collections()** (example code snippet below), that appear to supply the functionality your asking for:

```
EXPORT mxArray* mongo_get_databases(struct mongo_* conn) {
    bson out;
    mxArray* ret;
    int count = 0;
    bson_iterator it, databases, database;
    int i = 0;

    if (mongo_simple_int_command((mongo*)conn, "admin", "listDatabases", 1, &out) != MONGO_OK) {
        bson_destroy(&out);
        return 0;
    }
    bson_iterator_init(&it, &out);

    ...

    bson_destroy(&out);
    return ret;
}
```